# How to display parameter value separated by comma in table in rtf using bi publisher

Tags: bi-publisher

I have tried to use extended function to separate these values but the problem is that I  am able to separate only one value.

[image]

https://isu.ifmo.ru/docs/XMLP/help/en_US/htmfiles/B25951_01/T421739T421827.htm

Comment: your web link is broken and your question is unclear. Can you explain things a little more please?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use some text processing functions on each of the parameter. Say, if `$name` is the parameter which contains the comma separated data, then

```
<?xdofx:Instr($name,',',1)?> will give you the position of the comma in the text.
```

Then `<?xdofx:substr($name,1, Instr($name,',',1)-1)?>` will return the text before the comma.

And. `<?xdofx:substr($name,Instr($name,',',1)+1, length($name))?>` will return the text after the comma

```
first,last
6
first
last
```